# How to pass an array in $match that I got from a $lookup operation in the same aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I ran the aggregate query mentioned below

```json
[{
  $match: {
    type_of_booking: "fcl"
  }
},
{
  $addFields:
  {
    blacklist_arr:
      "$blacklist_company.blacklists",
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    company_id: 1,
    company_name: 1,
    blacklist_arr: 1
  }
},
{
  $match:
  {
    company_id: {
      $nin: "$blacklist_arr",
    }
  }
}]
```

This query gives the following error: **$nin needs an array**
But the value that I am passing to **$nin** operator is an array. I don't know why mongo is throwing such an error. Following is the value that I am passing to **$nin** operator:

```json
{
  "_id": "...",
  "company_id": "...",
  "company_name": "ABC Motors",
  "blacklist_arr": [
    "a", "b", "c"
  ]
}
```

As you can see above the variable **blacklist_arr** is an array then too mongo is throwing the error of **$nin** needs an array. Kindly help me with this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$match does not accept raw aggregation expressions. Instead, use a $expr query expression to include aggregation expression in $match.

```
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $not: {
          $in: [
            "$company_id",
            "$blacklist_arr"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```